# How to supply inital state to useReducer with passed in prop component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a table component and I'm passing in data via a variable named products. The component can display products if I map it, but it won't pass to an initial state variable object.
My goal is to call data.map inside Table.body component.
Thanks!

```
function exampleReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_SORT':
            if (state.column === action.column) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    data: state.data.slice().reverse(),
                    direction:
                        state.direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending',
                }
            }

            return {
                column: action.column,
                data: _.sortBy(state.data, [action.column]),
                direction: 'ascending',
            }
        default:
            throw new Error()
    }
}
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import _ from 'lodash'



function TableSorter({products}) { PROBLEM STARTS HERE
    const initialState = {
        column: null,
        data: products, PROBLEM STARTS HERE
        direction: null,
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(exampleReducer, initialState)

    const { column, data, direction } = state
        
    console.log(`products: ${products}`)
    console.log(`initial state data: ${data}`)

    return (
        <Table sortable celled fixed>
            <Table.Header>
            </Table.Header>
            <Table.Body>
                {products && products.map(({name, expiration_date, sku, category, price, shipment_batch}) => (
                    <Table.Row key={name}>
                        <Table.Cell>{name}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{expiration_date}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{sku}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{category}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{price}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{shipment_batch}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                ))}
            </Table.Body>
        </Table>
    )
}

export default TableSorter
```

[image: Displayed in the console is what products is displaying vs what initial state data is displaying.]

New Edit: the component that calls TableSorter
It makes an axios call to a localhost server and passes the data to TableSorter. I want it in a component form so that it's reusable later on in the future since I'll probably use it in another page.
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import TableSorter from "../Components/TableSorter";

```
function SearchFilter() {

    const login_url_string = "http://localhost:5000/search";

    const [productList, setProductList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(login_url_string)
            .then(res => {
                setProductList(res.data.products)
            })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <TableSorter products={productList}/>
        </div>
    )

}

export default SearchFilter
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with `useReducer`?

Comment: useReducer manipulates state and sorts the input data. I added useReducer for clarity.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this *but it won't pass to an initial state variable object*? Also I am not sure I understand *PROBLEM STARTS HERE*. I mean can you expound on it a little bit?

Comment: Yea sorry for non clarity, but my initialState variable's data field appears as null even though I initialize it the value of {products}. Whenever I pass initialState's data field to other variables, it appears as null instead of the initialized value of {products}. Hope I clarified things!

Comment: That's probably because on first render `TableSorter` gets a null in the `products` variable from the parent. The parent probably calls an API to get the products and then re-renders `TableSorter` with the data, but by that point the state of the child has already been set with the null. Show the component that renders  `TableSorter` and I will tell you for sure.

Comment: I totally agree with @codemonkey's assessment. I think `products` isn't the value you want on the initial render when the reducer is initialized. Is `TableSorter` a watered down example? I don't see the point of using `useReducer` either since you don't appear to be using `dispatch` to update the state. Please try to include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).